# How to use nested for loop to iterate over features of a layer?

Tags: python, pyqgis-3, pyqt5

I have a shapefile having features with duplicate IDs. I want to merge features with same IDs and take average of values of other field which are different. How is it possible in python in QGIS3?

[image]

Here, all other fields have same values of both features except last two fields. I want to merge the features and take average of values of last two fields. Here ID is same but last three fields are different because the file is the output of intersection, where one feature intersects with more than two features of other file so it is joining attribute of overlayed shapefile but input shapefile is repeating the ID and dividing a feature into two different features.
I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
for f in interLayer.getFeatures():  
        g =next(interLayer.getFeatures())
        if f['PIPE_ID']!=g['PIPE_ID']:
            f['k-new']=f['k']
            interLayer.updateFeature(f)
        if f['PIPE_ID']==g['PIPE_ID']:
            f['k-new']=(f['k']+g['k'])/2
            interLayer.deleteFeature(g.id())
            interLayer.updateFeature(f)
    interLayer.commitChanges()
```

Instead of delete, I want to merge features. But the code is not working for delete too. Here k-new is the field created to append averaged value.also, the duplicate ID can be more than two in some cases.

Comment: A few clearifications: In your example. field 8,9,10 and 11 are different in the two records you are showing. What should happen to fields 8 and 9? Also, do you know that field 1-7 are equal if field 1 (that I think is the id) is equal in the rows - if not, how should they be handeled? Do you want both records afterwards with the averaged values or just one? (If you want both records, disregard my questions about how to handle other fields) and at last: Do you always have two records with the same id or might there be more matching records? (please edit your question with answers)